# Calculating the duration between two dates in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm having some difficulty with an SQL query for reporting machine efficiency from a CNC monitoring system. The monitoring software records the duration the machines are in different states like machining, stopped, out of work setup etc. I want to total up the duration of these states for each machine per day to determine their efficiency.

Each state is given a start and end time I initially thought it would be a simple case of calculating the difference between the two dates but its not that simple. The problem is a state can start late one day and end in the early hours of the next which making it difficult to calculate state duration per day.

Here's a link to an Excel file that contains sample data
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71259257/example%20dataset.xlsx

I have come up with a fairly messy solution, I was going to use this as a basis to create a scheduled stored procedure that outputs the processed data to a separate table.

Here’s my query

```
DECLARE @date DATE;
SET @Date= '16 June 2015';

SELECT 
    Name, State, 
    CASE 
        WHEN LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 120), 10) = @Date 
             AND LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, EndDate, 120), 10) = @Date 
          THEN dbo.CalculateReportDuration(StartDate, EndDate) 
    END as Duration
FROM 
    [emc].[dbo].[TMB_MachineStateReport]
WHERE 
    CONVERT(Date, StartDate) = @Date 
    AND CONVERT(Date, EndDate) = @Date 

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    Name, State,
    dbo.CalculateReportDuration( LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, EndDate, 120), 10) + ' 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00', EndDate)  as Duration
FROM 
    [emc].[dbo].[TMB_MachineStateReport]
WHERE 
    CONVERT(Date, EndDate) = @Date 
    AND CONVERT(Date, StartDate) < @Date 

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    Name, State,
    dbo.CalculateReportDuration(StartDate, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartDate, 120), 10) + ' 23:59:59.9999999 +00:00')
FROM 
    [emc].[dbo].[TMB_MachineStateReport]
WHERE 
    CONVERT(Date, EndDate) > @Date 
    AND CONVERT(Date, StartDate) = @Date
```

What I want to know is does anyone have any better ideas? Ideally I’d like to create view but currently I'm relying on an SQL variable to hold a date value that I was going to increment all dates in the table using a while loop.

Code for CalculateReportDuration function

```
USE [emc]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[CalculateReportDuration]    Script Date: 06/20/2015 10:23:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateReportDuration]
            (
                @start DATETIMEOFFSET(7),
                @end DATETIMEOFFSET(7)
            )
            RETURNS INT
            AS
            BEGIN
                RETURN CAST(ROUND(DATEDIFF(SECOND, @start, @end) / 60.0, 0) AS INT) 
            END
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output, for the worst case scenario and preferably also SQL Fiddle link.

Comment: One could replace the records crossing midnight by multiple records, which don't. Process either procedurally or using a tally table. If you do/might need the original records (which are spanning multiple days) - use an additional table for the splits (plus those originally within a day's limits). - From there, you should be good for using views. -- If you are in control of the original input stream, you might want to switch to day based records - again (depending on foreign to this task requirements) instead of / in parallel to those spanning multiple days. (Sorry no code ready.)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the input stream and I don't want to modify the source table. I'm thinking maybe writing query to create a new table containing processed data then using a scheduled procedure to update the table from new records in the source table daily. Thanks for the reply :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `DATEDIFF()` on your two dates.

Here is a simple example:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minutes, GETDATE(), DATEADD(hours,2,GETDATE()))
```

Read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en_us/library/ms189794.aspx).

As the OP stated in the comments, he want's to have a row for each day. This means the time should be split per day and afterwards a calculation should be done.

Here is the code to achieve this. Just keep in Mind, due to the fact that it's done with a `CTE` you should be aware of statements which are over 100 days. ;-) Otherwise you need to adjust `MAX_RECURSION`.

```
IF(OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#timing') IS NOT NULL )
    DROP TABLE #timing

-- Create demo data
CREATE TABLE #timing(id int identity(1,1), startdate datetime, enddate datetime)

INSERT INTO #timing(startdate, enddate)
VALUES (DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()),DATEADD(MINUTE,10,GETDATE())), -- time spanning 1 day + 10 min
        (DATEADD(MINUTE,-70,GETDATE()),GETDATE()), -- spanning the current date just over 70 minutes
        (DATEADD(day,-3,GETDATE()),GETDATE()) -- spanning 3 days

        SELECT t.startdate, t.enddate, CONVERT(date,t.startdate), CONVERT(date,t.enddate) FROM #timing as t

;WITH cte AS(
    SELECT id, t.startdate as orig_startdate, t.enddate as orig_enddate,
        t.startdate, 
        DATEADD(SECOND,-1,CONVERT(datetime,DATEADD(day,1,CONVERT(date,t.startdate)))) as enddate,
        1 as iteration
    FROM #timing as t
    WHERE CONVERT(date, t.startdate) <> CONVERT(date, t.enddate)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.id, c.orig_startdate, c.orig_enddate, 
        CONVERT(datetime,DATEADD(day,c.iteration,CONVERT(date,c.orig_startdate))) as startdate,
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(day,c.iteration,CONVERT(date,c.orig_startdate)))
                = CONVERT(date, c.orig_enddate)
             THEN c.orig_enddate
             ELSE DATEADD(SECOND,-1,CONVERT(datetime,DATEADD(day,c.iteration+1,CONVERT(date,c.orig_startdate))))
        END as enddate,
        c.iteration+1 as iteration
    FROM cte as c
    WHERE DATEADD(day,c.iteration,CONVERT(date,c.orig_startdate)) <= CONVERT(date, c.orig_enddate)
) 
SELECT data.id, data.startdate, data.enddate, data.currentDate, data.minutesCurrentDay
FROM (
    SELECT c.id, c.orig_startdate as startdate, c.orig_enddate as enddate, 
        CONVERT(date,c.startdate) as currentDate, 
        DATEDIFF(minute,c.startdate,c.enddate)+1 as minutesCurrentDay
        --1 due to the timeshifting to get the days in line
    FROM cte as c
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, t.startdate, t.enddate, CONVERT(date, t.startdate) as currentDate, 
        DATEDIFF(minute,t.startdate, t.enddate) as minutesCurrentDay
    FROM #timing as t
    WHERE CONVERT(date,t.startdate) = CONVERT(date,t.enddate)
) as data
ORDER BY data.id, data.currentDate

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #timing
```

I've included demo code and a demo table structure as well. The point is just on the `startdate` and the `enddate` columns. You need to adjust it to your needed table structure. But that won't be to hard to add just a few columns without logic. :-)

Here is the demo input:

```
id          startdate               enddate
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1           2015-06-19 12:55:32.313 2015-06-20 13:05:32.313
2           2015-06-20 11:45:32.313 2015-06-20 12:55:32.313
3           2015-06-17 12:55:32.313 2015-06-20 12:55:32.313
```

And this is the result of the query:

```
id          startdate               enddate                 currentDate minutesCurrentDay
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- -----------------
1           2015-06-19 13:03:35.887 2015-06-20 13:13:35.887 2015-06-19  657
1           2015-06-19 13:03:35.887 2015-06-20 13:13:35.887 2015-06-20  794
2           2015-06-20 11:53:35.887 2015-06-20 13:03:35.887 2015-06-20  70
3           2015-06-17 13:03:35.887 2015-06-20 13:03:35.887 2015-06-17  657
3           2015-06-17 13:03:35.887 2015-06-20 13:03:35.887 2015-06-18  1440
3           2015-06-17 13:03:35.887 2015-06-20 13:03:35.887 2015-06-19  1440
3           2015-06-17 13:03:35.887 2015-06-20 13:03:35.887 2015-06-20  784
```

Btw. the `ORDER BY` in the result around the subquery isn't needed if you won't the result in an ordered state.

Comment: I wish it was that straight forward you see I want to get state duration per day and as the dates can be over two days it throws the figures off. CalculateReportDuration is a stored function that already uses DATEDIFF() I'll edit my post and add the code for it.

Comment: Ah okay. You want to get the following? Starts day one at 12 o'clock ends next day at 8 o'clock. You want 2 results. One for day one which counts 12 hours and one for day 2 which counts 8 hours. Right?

Comment: Yes thats what I'm after

Comment: Well no problem. I'm currently on my phone. I will update my answer later when I'm at home. Should've that big deal. :-)

Comment: I've added the code above. You just need the `SELECT` part (including `CTE`) for you. Everything else is just creating demo data structure for direct execution for a fast example. Hopefully this will help you. Ah btw. I return the time in minutes. If you don't like it, just adjust the `DATEDIFF` as needed. :-)

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks for taking the time to write that query

Comment: No problem. Nice that it helped you. You get the adaption done? :-) Just for my statistics, on how much rows did you run this code? How long does it take? :-)

Comment: The query worked really well I’ve run it on the entire table which has 12267 rows it returned 12500 and took 00:00:00.290 to execute. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Nice to help you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So something like this?

```
declare @start date, @end date
set @start = '20150616'
set @end = dateadd(day, 1, @start)

SELECT 
    Name, State,
    datediff(second,
      case when StartDate < @start then @start else StartDate end,
      case when EndDate > @end then @end else EndDate end) / 60.0 as Duration
FROM 
    [emc].[dbo].[TMB_MachineStateReport]
WHERE 
    EndDate > @start 
    StartDate < @end
```

This takes everything where the range overlaps with the given day and calculates the time either from the start / end of the row or start / end of the day, depending on which one is on the day of question.

Didn't test this so hopefully it works.

Comment: That worked its much more concise than mine :-)  So there isn’t away around using the variables? I had hoped to create a view so I could easily create some charts in excel. Also how would you show the result for every day would it just be a while loop increment @start?
Thanks for your help

Comment: You want a range of days and calculate the amounts for each day? You'll just need a date table (=table with one row for each day) and then join use that in this query. @start = day from the table, \@end = day from the table + 1

Comment: OK thanks one more question then I'll mark this as answered. How would recommend displaying the results of this query in an excel spreadsheet because as far as I'm aware you can't use variables in the query with excel?

Comment: Sorry I don't really know that much about excel

Comment: @user515031: Possibly use some developer/reporting tool, which is capable of exporting (to) Excel - if you have no way of setting up a view, which could be queried from Excel straight.